# Android: Array Index Out Of Bounds Error

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, android-studio

I am trying to convert a string containing date to a char array and then extract the month and convert it.

I'm using API, the server provide date in the format: "2015-04-10", I'm trying to convert this into: "10 April, 2015."

1. Im storing the date received from server is in a string.
2. I'm converting the entire string into a char array.
3. I'm running a loop through this array and separating it into three arrays: 
   YEAR, MONTH, DAY.
4. I'm separately converting these arrays to strings.
5. Then I'm comparing the 'month' string to values and then assigning the month name to it, using if-else conditions.
6. Lastly, I'm adding the three strings as per the order I want.

Android Studio says: `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=5`

Here is my code: ('temp' is the string containing the date)

```
//TODO: Here lies the method which will apparently convert the movie string to human read-able format...... Use it with caution.
    char release[] = temp.toCharArray();
    Log.d("LOG", release.toString());

    char date[] = new char[2];
    char year[] = new char[4];
    char month[] = new char[2];

    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {

        try {
            if (i > 4 && i < 7) {
                month[i] = release[i];
            }

            if (i < 4) {
                year[i] = release[i];    // ---> Android Studio says error on this line...
            }

            if (i > 7 && i < 10) {
                date[i] = release[i];
            }
        } catch (Error error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    String monthString = month.toString();
    String dateString = date.toString();
    String yearString = year.toString();
    String finalReleaseDate;

    if (monthString.contentEquals("01")) {
        monthString = "January";
    } else if (monthString.contentEquals("02")) {
        monthString = "February";
    } else if (monthString.contentEquals("03")) {
        monthString = "March";
    } else if (monthString.contentEquals("04")) {
        monthString = "April";
    } else if (monthString.contentEquals("05")) {
        monthString = "May";
    } else if (monthString.contentEquals("06")) {
        monthString = "June";
    } else if (monthString.contentEquals("07")) {
        monthString = "July";
    } else if (monthString.contentEquals("08")) {
        monthString = "August";
    } else if (monthString.contentEquals("09")) {
        monthString = "September";
    } else if (monthString.contentEquals("10")) {
        monthString = "October";
    } else if (monthString.contentEquals("11")) {
        monthString = "November";
    } else if (monthString.contentEquals("12")) {
        monthString = "December";
    }

    finalReleaseDate = dateString + " " + monthString + ", " + yearString;
    movieModel.setReleaseDate(finalReleaseDate);
```

The message in logcat is:       `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=5`   (I have marked the line at which this error is shown..)

Please help!!

Comment: Try using SimpleDateFormat, it will save you a lot of pain: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: a clear error would be , let's say `i=5` so `month[i]` exception , do some debugging and do follow the above suggestion

Comment: You are an declare a array with size 2:
    char month[] = new char[2];  

And making a loop larger than this
for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {

        try {
            if (i > 4 && i < 7) {
                month[i] = release[i];
            }
...

You must use local index in yours arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***First***, you method is not the best way to convert *number month* to *string month*. It should be easier and more stable to convert it by using `Date` and [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) method.

---

***Second***, you have marked the wrong line for the crash.
This crash `(java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: ***length=2; index=5***)` tells you that ***index is 5*** and ***array length is 4***.

```
if (i < 4) {
   year[i] = release[i];  //index 5 cannot be called here and year lenght is 4
}
if (i > 4 && i < 7) {
   month[i] = release[i]; //index 5 is called here and month lenght is 2
}
if (i > 7 && i < 10) {
   date[i] = release[i];
}
```

Crash is happening because you are calling `month[5] = release[5];` and month length is only 2.

*To avoid this change your code to:*

```
if (i<4) {
    //2015 index  0,1,2,3
    year[i] = release[i];
} else if (i>4 && i<7) {
    //04 index  5,6
    month[i-5] = release[i];
} else if (i>7 && i<10) {
    //10 index 8,9
    date[i-8] = release[i];
}
```

---

***Third***, if you want to get year, month, day in this way it is easier in this way.

```
String [] date_splited = server_string.split("-");
String year  = date_splited[0];
String month = date_splited[1];
String day   = date_splited[2];
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: P.S. In the 4th para, it should be `String year = date_splited[0]`.... .. Thanks for explanation!!

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating over *i* from 0 to 11
**release** array contains 10 digits only so you should iterate from 0 to 9

Oh Wait that is not your problem, you main problem that **year** only contains 4 objects from 0 to 3 so you cannot get item *i* when *i* is greater that 3

Is that all I guess not...
the log cat says the `index=5` so the error occurred when *i* is 5, but the line you are saying is included when *i* is smaller than 4, So I guess you read the log cat wrong.

And Also it says the length is 2 so it crashed when reading either **date** array or **month** array but no way when it read the **year** array

I brief as @Ken Wolf Wolf in the comment you can use `SimpleDateFormat`

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd", Locale.getDefault());
Date date = simpleDate.parse("");
simpleDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM, yyyy.", Locale.getDefault());
String newFormatString = simpleDate.format(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not occuring at the place that you say. It probably occurs at the first or the thrid if statement. Because date[] and month[] are both only 2 in length, and you are trying to access that with index higher than 2.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way should be using SimpleDateFormat as Omar marked.
Once you have a Date (or a Calendar maybe depending the use you will give to the information) you can use the local settings to translate it.

Answer (score 0):

why you use char[] ? you can use String[] directly. In string there is split method available. So using split method you can separate date month and year. You can use below code:

```
String date=  "2015-04-10";
String[] temp= date.split("-");
```

temp[0] is 2015, temp[1] is 04 and temp[1] is 10.